# what is the property for the size of a List in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

How do you access the size of a List<> in c#? In an array it's array.length, but what is the property for a List<>?

Answer (score 27):

If you want to know how many elements are in the list then use the Count property.

```
int numElements = list.Count;
```

On the other hand if you want to know how many elements the backing storage of the `List<T>` can currently handle then then use the Capacity property.

```
int size = list.Capacity;
```

Answer (score 15):

It is the [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx) property for List, and in almost any other collection class in the Framework. The Count property is also defined on the [ICollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2fx0ty0.aspx) interface.

Answer (score 5):

The Count property will give you the number of objects in the list.